# How do I use JS String Interpolation to insert Shopify sections? ('not a valid section type')

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'm building a 'view' template for certain blogs' tags. I'm grabbing the pathname with javascript and trying to insert a hero section based on which tag the user is on. If I hardcode the blog name and tag into the section string, it works. But if I try to interpolate the variables into it, I get a liquid error.

The code:

```
const pathName = window.location.pathname;
let blog_div = document.getElementById('blog-hero');
let blogName = pathName.split('/')[2];
let tagName = pathName.split('/')[4];

return blog_div.innerHTML = `{% section 'blog--hero-${blogName}-blog--${tagName}' %}`;
```

Expected Output:
Section loads on screen

Actual Output:
Nothing on-screen. Error in HTML: 'Liquid error: Error in tag 'section' - 'blog--hero-(blogName)-blog--(tagName)' is not a valid section type'

Comment: Liquid is executed on the server, JavaScript is executed in the browser. You can go only from server to browser not the other way around. Depending on your setup you'll have to do this differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the Section Rendering API, [per the docs](https://shopify.dev/api/section-rendering).

But the JSON.parse() line didn't work. So I had to use the onload, readyState, and status methods [per the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText)

New code ended up looking like

```
const pathName = window.location.pathname;
let blog_div = document.getElementById('blog-hero');
let blogName = pathName.split('/')[2];
let tagName = pathName.split('/')[4];

let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', `/?section_id=blog--hero-${blogName}-blog--${tagName}`)
request.onload = () => {
    if(request.readyState === request.DONE) {
        if (request.status === 200) {
            blog_div.innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }
};

request.send(null);
```